# How to match regex pattern only up to certain character

Tags: python, regex

```
line =abcsdfs?a=name&ab=fsdfsd&c=sfssf
pattern = '\?a=(.+?)&'
match_pattern = re.search(pattern, line)
```

I get result as `?a=name&` and and `match_pattern.group(1)` as `name`

But if I remove word name I don't get NONE return?

```
line =abcsdfs?a=&ab=fsdfsd&c=sfssf
pattern = '\?a=(.+?)&'
match_pattern = re.search(pattern, line)
```

I get result as `?a=&ab=fsdfsd&`  and `match_pattern.group(1)` as `&ab=fsdfsd`

How can I stop it to go further. I mean how to get result None/ error if do `match_pattern.group(1)`

Comment: You need a better regex and you will not have such a problem

Comment: i dont quite get what youre asking for....

Comment: I am trying to check if "a=" exists if it's empty throw an error. "ab" is next parameter followed by "c" parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should match all symbols except '&':

```
pattern = '\?a=([^&]*)'
```

Comment: your's works as well but I can accept one answer :( thanks

Comment: The other answer is not working for last group not finished by '&'

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

```
pattern = '\?a=(.*?)&'
```

Note that `.+?` matches **1** or more characters; `.*?` matches **0** or more characters.

Of course, if what you are trying to do is to match URL query strings, regex is the wrong tool. Try the `urlparse` module:

```
import urlparse
url = 'abcsdfs?a=name&b=&ab=fsdfsd&c=sfssf'
url = urlparse.urlsplit(url)
qs = url.query
qs = urlparse.parse_qs(qs, keep_blank_values=True)
print [qs['a'][0], qs['b'][0], qs['c'][0]]
```

Comment: The regex is not working for last name/value pair not having '&' at the end.

Comment: I think @user2661518 is parsing URL, and name/value can be at the end of the parameter line.

Comment: @Robᵩ yup it won't end with &